# Как разобрать условия в sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой функцией можно отдельно разобрать параметр, передаваемый в качестве аргумента в функцию ***filter***?

Код

> filters_clause = Record.start>='2017-07-17'
>
> print(filters_clause)

Выдаст

> records.start >= :start_1

Необходимо, чтобы вместо *:start_1* было значение, уже обработанное функцией *process_bind_param*. Или, как можно самому вызвать функцию *process_bind_param*?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

from __future__ import ( division, absolute_import,
                         print_function, unicode_literals )

import time

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, attributes
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, Integer, String


Base = declarative_base()


class EpochTime(TypeDecorator):
    impl = Integer

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if isinstance(value, unicode):
            if value.isdigit():
                return value

            if len(value) == 10:
                value = time.mktime(time.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d"))
            elif len(value) == 13:
                value = time.mktime(time.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d %H"))
            elif len(value) == 16:
                value = time.mktime(time.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))

        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(value))


class Record(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'records'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    start = Column(EpochTime)


engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
session.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

record = Record(name = 'Record 1', start = '2017-07-16')
session.add(record)
record = Record(name = 'Record 2', start = '2017-07-17')
session.add(record)
record = Record(name = 'Record 3', start = '2017-07-18')
session.add(record)

session.commit()


filters_clause = Record.start>='2017-07-17'
s = session.query(Record).filter(filters_clause)
res = s.all()
names = [i.name for i in Record.__table__.c]
rows = [[row.__dict__.get(i) for i in names] for row in res]

for row in rows:
    print(row)

print(0, s)
print(1, filters_clause)
```

Comment: Я лично, так с виду, не вижу никакой проблемы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, код падает с какой-то ошибкой? В момент Record.start>='2017-07-17' идет что-то не так?

Comment: Нет, код выполняется исправно, фильтрация происходит правильно. Дело в том, что мне надо передавать параметры filters_clause для обработки в javascript, для этого условие мне надо преобразовать в строку...

Comment: Отмечу, что мне не надо передавать значение '2017-07-17', а нужно передать уже обработанное функцией process_bind_param значение (в данном примере - это '1500235200.0').

Comment: То есть, перевети дату в абсолютное время? Вот так подойдет? time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())

Comment: Нет, не подойдёт ((
Спасибо, что пытаетесь помочь мне! ))
Функцию, которую Вы написали выше я уже указал в функции process_bind_param. И она работает - при выполнении запроса. Но я не знаю, как её вызвать отдельно для самостоятельного разбора параметров filters_clause.

Comment: Лобового решения как преобразовать объект filter_clause в time.time я придумать сейчас не могу. Нужно смотреть структуру класса, какие поля есть, какие методы .__doc__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45176148/2357007), который я получил в англоязычной ветке Сообщества:

Необходимо использовать [`literal_binds`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined):

```
print(filters_clause.compile(engine, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
# records.start >= 1500274800.0
```

Но, в любом случае, не забывайте о SQL injection при использовании `literal_binds`.